# Java 10.1 Eclipse Oxygen 3a No exception of type InstanceAlreadyExistsException can be thrown; an Exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen, java-10, eclipse-classpath

I have added the java.management module to my build path:

```
Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Modulepath -> Is modular -> Edit
```

I'm having this issue with:

```
InstanceAlreadyExistsException
MBeanRegistrationException
NotCompliantMBeanException
MalformedObjectNameException
```

If I look at these sources, they all extend Exceptions that are in the classpath (included modules) and go all the way up to java.lang.Exception that implements Throwable. For example:

```
in javax.management InstanceAlreadyExistsException extends OperationsException
in javax.management OperationsException extends JMException
in javax.management JMException extends java.lang.Exception
in java.lang Exception implements Throwable
```

So how on Earth is InstanceAlreadyExistsException not a subclass of Throwable?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/management/InstanceAlreadyExistsException.html

Comment: *How on Earth is InstanceAlreadyExistsException not a subclass of Throwable?*.. you just didn't attempt to traverse the complete tree up.
[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/management/InstanceAlreadyExistsException.html) => [2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/management/OperationsException.html) => [3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/management/JMException.html) => [4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) ? What other than that is your actual concern?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, InstanceAlreadyExistsException subclasses Throwable but I'm getting an error that it can't be thrown because it doe not subclass Throwable.  In Java 8 I did not get this error.  Why in Java 10 is it not considered a subclass of Throwable?

Comment: Well, I missed the fact, that you've pasted the error logs as the question title itself. Also to notice are you certain that the module `java.management` resolved?

Comment: Since you don’t have the qualified name in the error message, you should verify that the name `InstanceAlreadyExistsException` is truly resolved to the intended `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException`. In other words, check the `import` statements (other sources of errors would be type variables  or inherited nested classes of the same name, but those are less likely for a name like `InstanceAlreadyExistsException`).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand what precisely you configured in the build path settings. You shouldn't have to configure anything there but simply add `requires java.management;` to the `module-info.java`.

Besides that, this sounds like a bug in eclipse, but maybe it is already fixed (e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533644 sounds related).

Can you try with a recent integration build from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/, and if the problem still exists, report a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org (if possible with a complete self contained example that shows the problem)?